# Questions regarding properties of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> a)Let $A$ and $B$ be two elements of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ , and $\Delta(z)$ be the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $A+zB$. Show that if $deg(\Delta) \leq 1$, then $AB=BA$.
>
> b)Let $A$ and $B$ be two elements of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, suppose that for all complex $z$, $A+zB$ is diagonalisable. Show that $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure of your claim?

Let us take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Then $A+zB=\begin{pmatrix} 2z & 1-z \\ z & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and its characteristic polynomial is $\chi(X)=X^2-2zX+z^2-z$ and consequently $\Delta(z)=4z$. You can also verify that $AB-BA=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I agree sir , this problem was given by my teacher maybe he forgot something

Comment: yes , but anyway , the problem is false